# No data is shown in datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I try to load the page the datatable is empty. Using the `<h:dataTable ... />` the data shows up in the rows. However after further inspection the list is actually written....but it seems like it uses the toString() of the list directly in the value attribute of the datatable. What is wrong?

Backing bean

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class QuestionTableBacking {

    @Inject
    private QuestionServiceLocal questionService;

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        return questionService.getAllQuestions();
    }
}
```

Facelet file

```
        <h:form>

           <p:dataTable value="#{questionTableBacking.allQuestions}" var="question" >
               <p:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{question.description}" />
               </p:column>

               <p:column>
                   <h:link outcome="report" value="Rapporter" />
               </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>

        </h:form>
```

This is what I see in firebug

```
<p:datatable value="[com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Question@7cf9175c, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Question@456cd91d, com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Question@6d222286,..... var="question">
               <p:column>
               </p:column>

               <p:column><a href="/myapp/report.faces">Report</a>
               </p:column>
           </p:datatable>
```

POM file ( they are contained in correct parent elements )

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

> Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui
>   declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.

Complete file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/">

<h:head>
    <title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="templates/masterLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="windowTitle">Question</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <div id="page-intro">
                <h2>Titile</h2>

                <p>Blah blah</p>
            </div>

            <h:form>
                <div class="question-filter-container">
                    <o:inputTextFilter id="quesiton-filter" styleClass="input-text question-filter" for="question-table"
                                       expression="#{question.description}"
                                       promptText="" />
                </div>

                <o:dataTable value="#{questionTableBacking.allQuestions}" var="question" rowKey="#{question.id}"
                             id="question-table" pageSize="25" applyDefaultStyle="false"
                             cellspacing="0">
                    <f:facet name="below">
                        <o:dataTablePaginator id="paginator" pageNumberPrefix="Side" pageCountPreposition="av"
                                              styleClass="question-paginator" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <o:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{question.description}" />
                    </o:column>
                    <o:column bodyClass="question-operations">
                        <h:link outcome="report" value="Report" />
                    </o:column>
                </o:dataTable>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#{question.description}` should be turned into `String` value that is inside the currently iterated `question` objects `.description` propety , isn't that what you see in the output? if that the case , then its all fine...

**EDIT**

after looking at your question update it seems that you haven't added primefaces jar to your project...

have you added xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui to your xhtml file?

Comment: have you included primefaces jar in your project class path ? are you aware that you are working with CDI ? cause you havent tagged your question as a cdi one, "@Named" and "@Inject" is not JSG anotations...

Comment: if you want to use primefaces library you must add it to your project, the same way you added jsf jars

Comment: try to remove / re -add the primefaces jar file and maybe refresh your project , maybe reopen the eclipse...

Comment: can you post the complete  xhtml  ?  you might be missing  he following attribute xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui

Comment: The same thing happens with Openfaces...yes I will, I changed to Openfaces now and the same thing happens there so I just post it with that component library instead

Comment: so it means that the way that you are adding library jars to you project is not working... try to add the jar manually from the eclipse or netbeans  instead of Maven...

Comment: But the strange thing is that it worked the last time I worked on the project (that means yesterday) and today it doesn't work.

Comment: check what changes have been done in the project... I'm not familiar with maven... but maybe something was changed ?

Comment: try adding manually primefaces.jar to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/

Comment: But I don't understand why I should, it has worked all the time

Comment: maybe there were some changes in primefaces maven.... dunno , check to see if adding manually fixes this...

Comment: Thats the strangest thing. I changed sun-web.xml to glassfish-web.xml earlier today, that was the cause!

Comment: told you so :) "check what changes have been done in the project"

Comment: But why should that cause total mess up?

Comment: well I'm not an expert to glassfish, but that change somehow damaged your pom / primefaces jar loading